# Switch case em botão submit de acordo com ID do botão

Tags: php, mysql, switch

Tenho 7 botões de submit em um formulário. Sendo:

Quatro desse:

```
<input type="submit" id="chamado1" class="mr-abre-btn" value="Abrir chamado">
```

Dois desse:

```
<input type="submit" id="chamado2" class="mr-abre-btn" value="Encaminhar chamado">
```

E um desse:

```
<input type="submit" id="chamado3" class="mr-encerra-btn" value="Encerra chamado">
```

O problema é que estou tentando fazer um switch case ou um if no value de um `input hidden` que tenho. Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="situacao_id" value="
<?php
    $situacao_chamado = $_POST['id'];
            switch ($situacao_chamado) {
                    case 'chamado1':
                        echo "1";
                        break;
                    case 'chamado2':
                        echo "3";
                        break;
                    case 'chamado3':
                        echo "3";
                        break;
                }
                ?>"
```

Porém, quando busco por essa variavel:

```
$situacao_chamado = $_POST['id'];
```

Acaba gerando o erro abaixo:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\form\formulario.php on line 167 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010242264{main}( )...\formulari.php:0 20.0111307088include( 'C:\wamp64\www\form\formulario.php' )...\formulario.php:44 ">
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade de 7 botões? Por quê há botões repetidos? Saiba que o valor do atributo `id` não é passado para o PHP através da requisição. Os únicos valores serão o par `name`/`value`. Ao fazer `$_POST["id"]` você está tentando pegar o valor de um campo com `name="id"`, que não existe na pergunta. Se realmente fizer sentido essa quantidade de botões, defina o atributo `name` e verifique ele no PHP. Lembre-se que o valor será `value`, não `id`.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Preciso de vários input, pois o formulário é dinamico, são perguntas de sim e não e dependendo da resposta leva a outra pergunta, assim ele tem em determinada pergunta o encerramento do chamado ou abertura do chamado. E os Inputs aparecem em determinadas perguntas. Foi a maneira mais objetiva que consegui criar., obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre porque o `$_POST['id']` busca um input que tenha `name="id"`, basta arrumar seus inputs colocando um `name`, assim ele pegará os inputs que possuem o `name="id"` e dará a eles os valores determinados pelos `value=""`

```
<input type="submit" name="id" id="chamado1" class="mr-abre-btn" value="Abrir chamado">

<input type="submit" name="id" id="chamado2" class="mr-abre-btn" value="Encaminhar chamado">

<input type="submit" name="id" id="chamado3" class="mr-encerra-btn" value="Encerra chamado">
```

No seu PHP basta trocar os case:

```
switch ($situacao_chamado) {
    case 'Abrir chamado':
        echo "1";
        break;
    case 'Encerrar chamado':
        echo "3";
        break;
    case 'Encaminhar chamado':
        echo "3";
        break;
}
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema porém acredito que o melhor seria colocar radioButtons e apenas um input submit

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, resolvi o meu problema, modifiquei um pouco para a minha necessidade. Obrigado